# AngularJS binding a variable to an array related to the variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm a Japanese student. So my English isn't easy to read. I'm sorry.

I made prime numbers list by using AngularJS. A user inputs two values, *valFrom* and *valTo*. The list is built by the two numbers.

I want to bind to input values to the list. When I type in the inputs, the list changes by the values dynamically. But it doesn't. When I typed in the inputs, list doesn't change. I want to bind the values to the list.

The following is what I made. Values aren't sorted because Object is used, not Array.

**This is index.html.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja" ng-app="MYAPP">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js">   </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="inputCtrl">
        <h1>Make prime number list from {{fromVal}} to {{toVal}}</h2>
        <input type="number" ng-model="fromVal"><br>
        <input type="number" ng-model="toVal"><br>

        <!-- prime numbers list -->
        <div ng-controller="primeListCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="(val, flag) in primeFlags">
                {{val}}</td><td>{{flag==true? "is prime": "isn't prime"}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('MYAPP', []).

controller('inputCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.fromVal = 10;
    $scope.toVal = 50;
}).

controller('primeListCtrl', function($scope){
    /* 
        If primeFlags[i + ""] is true, i is prime number.
        Keys are string, values are boolean. 
    */
    $scope.primeFlags = {};

    // fill with true
    for(var i = 2; i <= $scope.toVal; i++){
        $scope.primeFlags[i+""] = true;
    }
    // set false
    for(var i = 2; i <= $scope.toVal; i++){
        for(var j = 2; j < i; j++){
            if(i%j === 0){
                $scope.primeFlags[i+""] = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I think the reason why input values doesn't bind to the list is that *primeFlags* aren't changed. When input values are changed, *primeFlags* isn't changed. So, the list isn't updated.

I'm thinking two solutions. First, Watching input values by using *$scope.$watch()*. Second, Watching input values by using *$broadcast() and $on()*. When the values are changed, remake *primeFlags*. But, I think that the solutions are not good. Are there better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your list of primes completely dynamic? If so, you can create your prime list on a function and then use the result of that function in your repeater:

```
$scope.primeFlags = function(){
      var primeList = {};
      // fill with true
      for(var i = 2; i <= $scope.toVal; i++){
          primeList[i+""] = true;
      }
      // set false
      for(var i = 2; i <= $scope.toVal; i++){
          for(var j = 2; j < i; j++){
              if(i%j === 0){
                  primeList[i+""] = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
      }

      return primeList;
    };
```

and on the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(val, flag) in primeFlags()">
```

If you can establish some sort of boundary, I suppose it's more efficient to create the list of primes in advance and then on your function just show a subset of that list:

```
app.controller('primeListCtrl', function($scope){
    /* 
        If primeFlags[i + ""] is true, i is prime number.
        Keys are string, values are boolean. 
    */
    var primeList = [];
    // fill with true
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
        primeList[i] = {id: i, flag: true};
    }
    // set false
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
        for(var j = 2; j < i; j++){
            if(i%j === 0){
                primeList[i].flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.primeFlags = function(){
      return primeList.slice($scope.fromVal, $scope.toVal);

    };
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="val in primeFlags()">
                {{val.id}}&mdash;{{val.flag==true? "is prime": "isn't prime"}}
            </div>
```

Comment: >> Is your list of primes completely dynamic?
No. Thanks to you, I got new way. I knew that some functions in $scope is called, if anything has been changed.